# Use Django template tags with Alpine.js x-text

Tags: javascript, django, alpine.js

I'm using [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev/) in my Django templates and so far I've been quite happy with the results.

However, I would like to use [Django template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/) for instance [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) on a value computed by Alpine.js. For now, I am formatting the number directly in Alpine.js and my code look like this:

```
<div x-data="{rawNumber: 1.23456,
              get formattedNumber() {
                  return Math.round(rawNumber + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
              } 
              }">
    My formatted number is <span x-text="formatNumber"></span>
</div>
```

What I'm looking for is a way to use Django template tags on the value computed by Alpine.js. A very naïve implementation (which of course generates error) would look like this:

```
<div x-data="{rawNumber: 1.23456}">
    My formatted number is  {{ <span x-text="rawNumber"></span>|floatformat:2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use server side Django template tags in frontend javascript code after the template was rendered. Just use javascript functions for frontend stuff.

Comment: Indeed, take makes sense. Thanks for clarification